# How can I assign a vim syntax group to a 'Foo( ... )'? For arbitrary ... including contained parenthesis

Tags: vim

I am trying to give my debug macros a different color, not just the macro names, but at least the opening and closing parenthesis in the same color.

As a test I'm current using the following line:

```
                      ,--- Uncolored paren!?
                     v
int foobar; Dout( (( ) ) ( ) ); f((char*)x);
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                 \__ all of this should be colored.
```

If I try the following syntax rule:

```
syn region Debug matchgroup=DebugDelim start=/Dout(/ end=/)/ contains=cParen
```

then this isn't working: the first closing parenthesis that should be part of cParen isn't part of any highlighting group anymore and remains therefore uncolored.

Is this a bug in vim or am I doing something wrong?

Note: cParen here is defined as 'usual' (in the vim's c.vim syntax file).

EDIT: After figuring out the answer to my previous question (namely that contained groups match inside the start and end pattern unless you use a matchgroup argument), I changed my question to what remains a question to me.

Answer (score 0):

After more than a week of research and trying things; the main conclusion is that vim's syntax system needs a redesign. It is flawed.

Having said that, the best answer would be 'it can not be done', because the system is just too broken; but -- with lots and lots of efforts a sort of horrible work around can be forged (for THIS case -- not for what I really needed) that looks as follows:

```vim
" Highlight my debug macros.

" A group with things that are normally already excluded from cParen.
syn cluster cwNotInParen contains=@cParenGroup,cCppParen,cErrInBracket,cCppBracket,@cStringGroup,@Spell

" Create a new cParen syntax group that will have Debug highlighting.
syn region cwDebugParen transparent matchgroup=cwDebugParenDelim contains=ALLBUT,@cwNotInParen
\       start='(' end=")\@="

" Define cParen last, so it will overrule the previous one.
syn clear cParen
syn region cParen transparent contains=ALLBUT,@cwNotInParen,cwDebugParen
\       start='(' end=')'

" Redefine cCppParen to also exclude cwDebugParen
syn clear cCppParen
syn region cCppParen transparent contained contains=ALLBUT,@cParenGroup,cErrInBracket,cParen,cwDebugParen,cBracket,cString,@Spell
\      start='(' skip='\\$' excludenl end=')' end='$'

" Redefine cCppBracket to also exclude cwDebugParen.
syn clear cCppBracket
syn region cCppBracket transparent contained contains=ALLBUT,@cParenGroup,cErrInParen,cParen,cwDebugParen,cBracket,cString,@Spell
\      start='\[\|<::\@!' skip='\\$' excludenl end=']\|:>' end='$'

" Add a syntax group for "Debug( ... );".
syn region cwDebugMacros transparent matchgroup=cwDebugMacrosDelim contains=cwDebugParen
\       start="\v\W(Debug|DoutFatal|DoutEntering|Dout|ASSERT|assert)\(@="hs=s+1
\       start="\v^(Debug|DoutFatal|DoutEntering|Dout|ASSERT|assert)\(@="
\       end="\v\);?"

hi link cwDebugMacrosDelim Debug       " Highlight 'Debug' and the close paren of that macro.
hi link cwDebugParenDelim Debug        " Highlight the open paren of the Debug macro.
```

This works as follows:

A new syntax group is created called `cwDebugParen`. It is basically the same as `cParen` but will have highlighting for the parenthesis. Because the syntax definition is containing `ALLBUT` in many places, this new group will now be accepted everywhere. It is possible - but not very convenient - to just replace the *whole* syntax file with your own and then add the new `cwDebugParen` to all `ALLBUT,...` lists, but in this case it is easier to remove `cParen` and redefine it after the definition of `cwDebugParen`, effectively hiding that because the last rule that matches will be used. Unfortunately the definition of `cParen` depends on some conditionals so the whole would get pretty complex still; therefore I just picked the one cParen definition that is used based on my .vimrc.

Because `cParen` doesn't have a `matchgroup` I found that its start pattern is *still* *also* matched by `cwDebugParen`?! -- this seems a bug to me but at least can be avoided by adding `cwDebugParen` to the `ALLBUT` list of `cParen`.

`cwDebugParen` itself *does* have a `matchgroup`, which is necessary for the syntax highlighting of the parens of course. Note that although it ends on the closing paren `')'`, I use a zero-match (`:help \@=`) because the same paren is needed to end the enclosing `cwDebugMacros` region. Note that using `end=')'me=s-1` would have the same effect here.

Finally a new region is added, `cwDebugMacros`, that starts at a pattern like `Debug(` and ends on `);`. The two `start=` arguments are necessary because they use a different highlight start (hs) since one starts at the beginning of the line while the other demands that there is a non-word character in front of `Debug`. Also the opening paren here is a zero-match because we need it to start the `cwDebugParen` region that we contain in this region (fortunately we *can* use a zero-match here; because `me=s-1` isn't support for `start`!?). That then will gobble up all input up till the closing paren, so we don't have to be afraid that our end will match a closing paren that isn't the closing paren of our debug macro. Note that I used `end="\v\);?"` with a question mark after the semi-colon so that IF the semi-colon directly follows the closing paren then it is also colored the same color (I like that) while if for whatever reason there is white-space (including comments) in between then things aren't broken - only the semi-colon isn't colored anymore then.

**Edit:** Added a redefine for cCppParen and cCppBracket which use the construct `ALLBUT=...,cParen,...` and therefore now also need to exclude `cwDebugParen`.